# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in react js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, arrayobject

I am new to react. The problem is when i am passing the array object in map function its throw the following error.

Here is the constructor where i have defined the array object.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          name: "",
          completed: false,
        },
      ],
      checkValue: false,
    };
  }
```

Now i am wondering the actual problem is coming from the handleChange and handleSubmit functions as i didn't know what exactly to write it here

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, this.state.data.name],
    });
    e.target.reset();
  };
```

Here is the map function where i have mapped the list items and Checkbox, delete button(i am only having trouble in saving the input in an array of list items these Checkbox and delete button are working perfectly)

```
render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center" style={{ color: "#f7c6c6" }}>
          todos
        </h1>
        <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label className="label" onClick={this.handleCheck}>
            ^
          </label>
          <input
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="new-todo shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white"
            placeholder="What needs to be done?"
          />
          <ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={"todo-" + index} className="div-list">
                  <input
                    className="check"
                    onChange={this.handleCheckChange}
                    type="checkbox"
                    style={{
                      cursor: "pointer",
                    }}
                    defaultChecked={this.state.data.completed}
                  />
                  <li
                    className="list-group-item disabled w-50 p-3 mx-auto"
                    style={{
                      textDecoration:
                        this.state.data.completed && "line-through",
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.name}
                  </li>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          {this.state.data.length > 0 && (
            <Display noOfTodos={this.state.data.length} />
          )}
          {this.state.checkValue && <Clear />}
        </form>
      </Fragment>
```

The above code is incomplete i know because i just want to know how to display that name element in the list group and nothing else so just ignore the rest of the code

Thank you in advance!!

**MainPage Component**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Clear from "./clear";
import Display from "./display";

class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          name: "",
          completed: false,
        },
      ],
      checkValue: false,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, { name: e.target.value, completed: false }],
    });
    e.target.reset();
  };

  handleDelete = (index) => {
    const newList = [...this.state.data];
    newList.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState({ data: newList });
  };

  handleCheck = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  handleCheckChange = () => {
    const { checkValue } = this.state;

    this.setState({ checkValue: !checkValue });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center" style={{ color: "#f7c6c6" }}>
          todos
        </h1>
        <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label className="label" onClick={this.handleCheck}>
            ^
          </label>
          <input
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="new-todo shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white"
            placeholder="What needs to be done?"
          />
          <ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={"todo-" + index} className="div-list">
                  <input
                    className="check"
                    onChange={this.handleCheckChange}
                    type="checkbox"
                    style={{
                      cursor: "pointer",
                    }}
                    defaultChecked={this.state.data.completed}
                  />
                  <li
                    className="list-group-item disabled w-50 p-3 mx-auto"
                    style={{
                      textDecoration:
                        this.state.data.completed && "line-through",
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.name}
                  </li>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          {this.state.data.length > 0 && (
            <Display noOfTodos={this.state.data.length} />
          )}
          {this.state.checkValue && <Clear />}
        </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

**Display Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Display extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="para">{this.props.noOfTodos} items left</p>
        <button type="button" className=" all btn btn-light p-1 mr-3">
          All
        </button>
        <button type="button" className=" act btn btn-light p-1 mr-3">
          Active
        </button>
        <button type="button" className=" comp btn btn-light p-1">
          Completed
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Display;
```

**Clear Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Clear extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" className="clr btn btn-light p-1">
        Clear completed
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Clear;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you were doing wrong was accessing the data array incorrectly and setting state incorrectly. i have fixed those 2 parts.
your MainPage components code should be like this ...

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Clear from "./clear";
import Display from "./display";

class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          name: "first todo",
          completed: false
        }
      ],
      checkValue: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      data: [
        ...this.state.data,
        {
          name: this.state.name,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    });
    e.target.reset();
  };

  handleDelete = (index) => {
    const newList = [...this.state.data];
    newList.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ data: newList });
  };

  handleCheck = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  handleCheckChange = () => {
    const { checkValue } = this.state;

    this.setState({ checkValue: !checkValue });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center" style={{ color: "#f7c6c6" }}>
          todos
        </h1>
        <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label className="label" onClick={this.handleCheck}>
            ^
          </label>
          <input
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="new-todo shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white"
            placeholder="What needs to be done?"
          />
          <ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={"todo-" + index} className="div-list">
                  <input
                    className="check"
                    onChange={this.handleCheckChange}
                    type="checkbox"
                    style={{
                      cursor: "pointer"
                    }}
                    defaultChecked={this.state.data.completed}
                  />
                  <li
                    className="list-group-item disabled w-50 p-3 mx-auto"
                    style={{
                      textDecoration:
                        this.state.data.completed && "line-through"
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.name}
                  </li>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          {this.state.data.length > 0 && (
            <Display noOfTodos={this.state.data.length} />
          )}
          {this.state.checkValue && <Clear />}
        </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

you can check it in CodeSandbox here. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-snow-dqbbc?file=/src/MainPage.js:0-3021

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221915/discussion-on-answer-by-mohammad-faisal-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-o).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 data: [...this.state.data, this.state.data[0].name]
```